# Linq to sql null value check in calculation

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have function which calculates quantity .Its working fine but some due to null values in field it does not return anything . these field can be null .i want to calculate only where both fields are not null. i think i need to use foreach but i dont know the way how can i use it here . 
Help appreciated

```
 private double Get_Quantity() 
    {
        try
        {
            double sum = 0;

            sum = (double)(from s in ManagerClass.oSqlData.table
                           where s.Demand.Order.Order_ID == Order_ID 
                           where s.Demand.Order.Order_Date >= ManagerClass.startDate && s.Demand.Order.Order_Date <= ManagerClass.EndDate

                           select s.ValueA - s.ValueB ).Sum();
            return sum;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a `where` clause to check that `valueA` and `valueB` are not null?

Comment: yes i did try that its not working

Comment: it should eliminate null values but its not working

Comment: Show what you tried, then. You can also try to debug and see what happens if you execute your linq code, but without the Sum(). Are the returned elements the ones you would expect?

Comment: .. the problem is due to null values ..either valueA or ValueB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this;

```
        sum = (double)(from s in ManagerClass.oSqlData.table
            where (s.Demand != null && s.Demand.Order != null && s.Demand.Order.Order_ID == Order_ID)
            && (s.Demand != null && s.Demand.Order != null && s.Demand.Order.Order_Date >= ManagerClass.startDate && s.Demand.Order.Order_Date <= ManagerClass.EndDate)
                  && s.ValueA != null
                  && s.ValueB != null
            select s.ValueA - s.ValueB).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
```

Comment: its not working still not returning due to null values

Comment: What do you mean "still not returning". Are you sure that your table data is correct ? I updated my answer posibility for no records. If there is no record to retrieve sum result will be 0.

Comment: there are few fields of valueA and ValueB which are null . its returning the correct result when there is no null value .

Comment: Seems that it is not relevant ValueA or ValueB values. Are you sure that where clauses are correct ? "(s.Demand != null && s.Demand.Order != null && s.Demand.Order.Order_ID == Order_ID)
            && (s.Demand != null && s.Demand.Order != null && s.Demand.Order.Order_Date >= ManagerClass.startDate && s.Demand.Order.Order_Date <= ManagerClass.EndDate)"

Comment: I provided you a query. I don't know about anything "Order_ID" or "ManagerClass.startDate" values. Would you try to remove Order_ID and Order_Date where clauses ?

Comment: that some order id does not exisit in demand table .thats why ..now how should i handle this problem

Comment: can u please tell me how can i check if this order id exsist in demand table only that it should calculate

Comment: "DefaultIfEmpty(-1)" return it as -1, so you can understand that there is no record with orderid or another filter.